# Need an alternative for .parse function

Tags: java, parsing

I am currently dealing with numbers with different bases. I am using the function Long.parseLong to convert a number from base int to its decimal value:

Long.parseLong("A", 16) to convert A which is a hexadecimal to its decimal value 10. I then use Long.toString(10, 16) to convert it back to A.

The problem now is that one of the entries in the problem set is "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" and when I use the Long.parseLong(); function, it returns an error because the size of the conversion can't fit to a Long. I tried to use Float, but I'm afraid that there is no Float.parseFloat(String, int) with the int as its radix.

Is there an alternative which I can use? 
BigInteger also doesn't have any parse function with the radix.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BigInteger` has [a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), which does radix conversion for you:

```
BigInteger num = new BigInteger("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", 16);
```

If you wish to convert back to hexadecimal, you can use [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString(int)):

```
String hex = num.toString(16);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed very helpful! I thought I was able to fully understand BigIntegers. Have a great day ahead mate!

Comment: @JonaziAlmocera Since this is a really good answer, you should consider **accepting** it.